# Sqlite joining two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

first let me say sorry for not finding answer on the online forum, but I don't even know how to search for and answer to my question.

I have some basic SQL knowledge.

I have two tables and I am trying to make some sort of join. I tried left join, but that doesn't give the correct results. I also tried with operator <= in "left join B on A.Id <= B.A_ID" but that didn't work either.

```
Table A
ID A_val1 A_val2...
1   x1     y1
2   x2     y2
3   x3     y3
.
.
8   x8     y8
9   x9     y9

Table B
ID A_ID B_Val
1   1     0
2   5     1
3   8     2
4   9     3
```

Results that I need: last 4 rows in Table A joined with table B

```
A_ID A_Val1 A_val2 B_val
6   x6     y6      1
7   x7     y7      1
8   x8     y8      2
9   x9     y9      3
```

Best regards,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join with a `LIMIT` query:

```
SELECT
    a.ID AS A_ID,
    a.A_Val1,
    a.A_val2,
    b.B_val
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, A_val1, A_val2
    FROM TableA
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT 4
) a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON a.ID = b.A_ID
ORDER BY
    a.ID;
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you very much Tim for this quick answer, it's very close but not quite there. I tried your demo with "Limit 8" and I only get 5 rows for answer.

Comment: @Gregc The problem is your sample data, not my answer.  Use a `LEFT JOIN` in my answer, and it will work.  [Check this updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dc9d97970c8c6728a8afb0ecbc8cf404).

Comment: With Left join, I get null values for A_ID 4. Is it even possible to extend B_Val from previous B.IDs until A_ID matches new B.A_ID? So ID 5 would still have b_Val 1 but A.ID= 4 would have B_val= 0 which isfrom row with B_ID =1?
A_ID A_Val1 A_val2 B_val
4   x4     x4      0
5   x5     y5      1
6   x6     y6      1
7   x7     y7      1
8   x8     y8      2
9   x9     y9      3

Comment: That's a very different requirement from what you asked, and I won't update the answer I have given.  But, I can imagine a few ways of doing that in SQLite, one of which uses a correlated subquery.  You might want to ask a new question.

Comment: As said I had no idea how to even ask, I just tried with a sample. I had no idea that this sample will lead to a wrong conclusion. I guess the problem is that I said last 4 rows. but yeah that was jsut a bad sample. my table is actually few million, and B table is up to 100. Wont this be just duplicating my question with just a little bit different sample? I am not a native english speaker and I don't know how to properly express to make my question easier to understand.

Comment: So if the B value be missing, do you want to take the closest previous value, or the closest following value?

Comment: yes the closest previoues value.
A_ID A_Val1 A_val2 B_val
4   x4     y4      0
5   x5     y5      1
6   x6     y6      1
7   x7     y7      1
8   x8     y8      2
9   x9     y9      3

Comment: [Check this updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a0aac5f06406f72cbb23c4c45fb88d9b), which seems to be the logic you want here.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
select     a.ID
          ,a.A_Val1
          ,a.A_val2
          ,b.B_val
from      a
left      join b in a.ID = b.A_ID
Where     a.ID > 5
```

-- OR

```
select    a.ID
          ,a.A_Val1
          ,a.A_val2
          ,b.B_val
from      a
left join b in a.ID = b.A_ID
Order by  a.ID desc
LIMIT     4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This assumes that the `ID` column would always be sequentially numbered from 1 onwards, which might not always be true.

Comment: ID column is autoincremented in both tables.